# Uncaught TypeError: undefined for Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

View code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="warning_modal">
  ...
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
if (<%= flash[:warning] %> === true ) {
  console.log("it's now in the function")
  $('#warning_modal').modal({
    show: true,
    keyboard: true
  });
}
```

My `console.log` runs and the error is at the `$('#warning_modal').modal({` line, it's saying `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. What could be causing this?

Note: I've required `bootstrap.js` in my `application.js` file as below, but this does appear to be a loading problem, since in the console, `$('#warning_modal')` finds the object but `$('#warning_modal').modal` returns undefined

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap.js
```

Also, I tried adding the bootstrap.js via a CDN as so, but it also didn't work.

```
<head>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: You have `=== true` instead of `== true`. Why?

Comment: Make sure your bootstrap is actually loaded in your document.

Comment: @ZeeTee how do I make sure it's loaded besides just requiring it in the `application.js` file?

Comment: I usually have a bootstrap.js file, not sure what you're using.

Comment: yes that's what I'm doing

Comment: You're using the modal plugin of another plugin that you don't know you even have loaded?

Comment: yes... but that's why i'm asking how do i check if it's loaded

Comment: Open up your browsers console and enter `$('#warning_modal').modal({
    show: true,
    keyboard: true
  });` The modal should load if you have bootstrap.js loaded

Comment: Yeah I amended the answer, but `.modal` is returning undefined. So then what else do I need to do to make `bootstrap.js` loaded?

Comment: Make a jsfiddle or give us the link. We need to see you application.js file at least.

Comment: Not sure how to use JSFiddle to show the `application.js` and the `require bootstrap.js` line so I just shared the `application.js` code snippet above. FWIW, I also tried using a CDN in the actual page... didn't work either

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

Your modal needs the id="warning_modal", not submit_modal

html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="warning_modal">
...
</div>
```

code:

```
if (<%= flash[:warning] %> === true ) {
console.log("it's now in the function")
$('#warning_modal').modal({
show: true,
keyboard: true
});
}
```

As per your update, try this order:

Try this order:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: oh that was a stupid copy/paste error on my part... it does have warning_modal, I've updated the question

Comment: Then we need more info. How about a jsfiddle?

Comment: Read this on another post and it makes no sense but try moving  `//= require jquery` below `//= require bootstrap.min`